# EditText inputType for numbers in a tablet device, always showing extra keys

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I am setting an EditText for a tablet device that takes only numbers, but an extra keypad with mathematical operators and extra options appear to the left of the numbers:

[image]

My EditText is defined like this:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_container"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:hint="123-4567890"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    >

</EditText>
```

If I set the *inputType* to "numberPassword" I get my desired result:

[image]

Running the app in a phone device, with the *inputType* set to "number", also displays what I want:

[image]

Why is it showing the extra keyboard part in a tablet device?

How can I get the EditText to display only numbers in the tablet, just as it does using a phone device or just as it does with the "numberPassword" inputType option?

Cheers!

Comment: This is how that keyboard is designed, If you want to show only the numbers AFAIK you will have to develop your own keyboard :)

Comment: Please understand that there are hundreds of different input method editors (soft keyboards) available for Android, both pre-installed and user-installed. All you are doing in `EditText` is providing hints for how best to present a keyboard. How those hints are interpreted is up to the developer of the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it showing the extra keyboard part in a tablet device?

Because it that's how it is designed.

> How can I get the EditText to display only numbers in the tablet,

You can't. If you need particular layout of keys, you'd need to implement this yourself.

Still, why would you even bother? User can have any keyboard he wants, even physical one so you should always filter what is being entered anyway. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter